# joomla 1.5 -> 3.1 migration with sql

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am just migrating a joomla 1.5 site to 3.1 manually, after some fallen trials with migration tools.
The site isn't too complicated so I have started with manual sql.
Content was migrated successfully, but the jos_menu make me a headache.

The next sql statement seems to be working, but the menu items can't be modified on the administrator page after the insertion:

```
Insert into try0715_menu 
(id, menutype, title, alias, link, type, published, parent_id, language, access ) 
select id+200, 'magyar-menu', name, alias, link, type, published, parent+200, 'hu-HU', 1   
from j15.jos_menu  
where menutype = 'mainmenu'
and type = 'component'
and published = 1
and componentid = 20;
```

ps.: I left the **rgt** and **lft** fields on 0 on the inserted records.

Can someone point my fault, or recommend any resource about how to transfer joomla menus by sql from 1.5 to 3.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A have just recognized that, JUpgrade module on http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/joomla-migration/11658 makes the menu table migration well.
Even more, the source code can be checked in the com_jupgrade-2.5.2\com_jupgrade\admin\includes\migrate_menus.php, it answers all of my questions about the migration of this table.